# I want to open my navigation bar but it wont seem to let me do it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, navigation

So im stuck trying to get the navagtion bar to open i have it so when it is clicked on it should be getting ride of the hide-links tag but it just seems to not toggle it and keeps the the ul hiden

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../styles/navstyle.css'
import { MdMenu } from 'react-icons/md';
import { MdClose } from 'react-icons/md';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function NavMenu () {
    const [ open, setOpen ] = useState(false);

    return(

        <div className="nav">
            <div className="moblie-menu-icon"
                onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} 
                role="button"
                >
                <MdMenu />
            </div>
            <ul className={ !setOpen ? 'nav-links' : 'nav-links hide-links'}>
                <div className="closeNavIcon" 
                onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} 
                role="button" 
                >
                    <MdClose />
                </div>
                <li className="link">
                    <NavLink to="/" exact>Home</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="link">
                    <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="link">
                    <NavLink to="/projects">Projects</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="link">
                    <NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is the css if you need it

```
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    background-color: var(--dark-bg);
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}

li {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: 0.3s ease background-color;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: var(--deep-dark);
}

a {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: var(--gary-1);
    outline: none;
}

.active {
    color: var(--white)
}

.moblie-menu-icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
    top: 1rem;
    width: 4rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    outline: none;
}

.closeNavIcon {
    display: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    * {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .moblie-menu-icon {
        display: block;
    }

    .hide-links {
        transform: translateY(calc(-100% - var(--top)));
    }

    .nav-links {
        --top: 1rem;
        display: inline-block;
        transition: 0.3s ease transform;
        background-color: var(--deep-dark);
        padding: 2rem;
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 300px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 1rem;
        top: var(--top);
        cursor: pointer;
    }


    .closeNavIcon {
        display: block;
        width: 3rem;
        margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    }

    .link {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

}
```

I tried switching classes or adding a show-links class when it would be clicked but nothing seemed to work

Comment: In  your CSS file, try placing the .hide-links  below .nav-links. Or else add the !important specifier to the .hide-links

Comment: You're testing `setOpen` for truthiness, but it's a function so is always truthy. I assume you mean to check `open` instead.

Comment: @RobinZigmond you are right. He have given setOpen for ternary.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at below line:

```
<ul className={ !setOpen ? 'nav-links' : 'nav-links hide-links'}>
```

Use **!open** instead of **!setOpen** and it should work fine.

Comment: If i set to !open it just keeps the dropdown open

Comment: Try using open instead of !open and check in dev tools if class is appending or not, if class is getting append and still drop down is open there might be an issue with css.